# Filter users with a join table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have tables for users, tags, and join table taggings.

I'm currently using `scope` to filter users through different variables, for example:

```
scope = scope.where('users.created_at > :created_after', created_after: params[:created_after])
```

I am trying to filter users by tags assigned to them (through a `has many` relationship).

In user model:

```
has_many :taggings, as: :taggable
has_many :tags, through: :taggings
```

User table:

```
╔════╦══════════════╦
║ id ║  name        ║
╠════╬══════════════╬
║  1 ║ Picard       ║ 
║  2 ║ Kirk         ║
║  3 ║ Sisko        ║
║  4 ║ Janeway      ║
╚════╩══════════════╩
```

Tags table:

```
╔════╦══════════════╦
║ id ║  Tag         ║ 
╠════╬══════════════╬
║  1 ║ TOS          ║  
║  2 ║ TNG          ║ 
║  3 ║ DS9          ║ 
║  4 ║ VOY          ║ 
╚════╩══════════════╩
```

Taggins table:

```
╔════╦═══════════╦═══════════════╦═══════════════════════╦
║ id ║  tag_id   ║ taggable_id   ║ taggable_type         ║ 
╠════╬═══════════╬═══════════════╬═══════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ 1         ║    1          ║  User                 ║
║  2 ║ 1         ║    4          ║  Organization         ║
║  3 ║ 2         ║    2          ║  User                 ║
║  4 ║ 1         ║    3          ║  User                 ║
╚════╩═══════════╩═══════════════╩═══════════════════════╝
```

I've tried something like:

```
SELECT * FROM users u
  JOIN taggings j, tags t
  WHERE t.tag = <tag>
    AND t.id = j.tag_id
    AND j.taggable_type = 'User'
    AND u.id = j.taggable_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a count and use having to stipulate that the user must have one or more tags:

```
tags = ["TOS", "TNG"]
User.joins(:tags)
    .where(tags: { tag: tags })
    .group(:id)
    .having(
      # Arel for "COUNT(tags.*) >= ?"
      Tag.arel_table[Arel.star].count.gte(tags.length)
    )
```

Since you're using a polymorpic assocation you probaly want to bake this into a module so that you can reuse it:

```
module Taggable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    has_many :taggings, as: :taggable
    has_many :tags, through: :taggings
  end

  class_methods do
    def with_tags(*tags) 
      joins(:tags)
        .where(tags: { tag: tags })
        .group(:id)
        .having(  
          Tag.arel_table[Arel.star]
             .count.gteq(tags.length)
        )
    end
  end
end
```

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include Taggable
end
```

Comment: There is also the alternative of using a subquery or a lateral join (on Postgres) if you want to be able to eager load the tags at the same time since you can't fetch rows on the joined table when grouping unless you're using MySQL/MariaDB which doesn't care about pesky stuff like SQL Standards or ambiguity.

Comment: This ended up working so well! Thank you, max.

Just a small note: there is a typo. `.count.gte(tags.length)` should be `.count.gteq(tags.length)`